# Using MVCContrib's WindsorControllerFactory with new Windsor Castle 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, mvccontrib

I'm trying to use `WindsorControllerFactory` (the latest 1.0.0.916 version) together with the new Windsor Castle 2.0 (again, the latest version). But I'm getting the

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Castle.Windsor, Version=1.0.3.0...

error when starting the Web application. Anyway, during writing of this question I managed to persuade the Web app to bind to new Castle's dlls by adding this block to the Web.config file:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Windsor" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.3.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Core" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.3.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.MicroKernel" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.3.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

So I guess I answered my own question, but I wanted to share this with anybody having the same problem. Or is there a better way (apart from compiling the MVCContrib sources myself)?

Comment: I guess the MVCContrib devs are waiting for Castle to release the other projects (components, transaction) to upgrade their dependencies...

Comment: I just had exactly the same problem! I chose to build MVCContrib myself though.

Comment: In the end I'll probably have to build it myself too, since they didn't provide strongly signed assemblies :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to build MvcContrib myself too, and put its source along with our project code.

Answer (score 0):

We use the same approach. There is one issue with the last available MvcContrib (v.2.0.96.0). It uses Castel.Windsor v.2.1.0.0 that is not compatible with the latest version of Castel.Windsor (2.5.1.0): AddComponentLifeStyle is obsolete. So you will have to change related MvcContrib code.

BTW, you can sign MvcContrib dlls without rebuilding them, for example with this tool: http://signer.codeplex.com/

Comment: This is a good point. Castle 2.5.1 is incompatible with the version that MVCContrib 2.0.96 needs. This is especially a problem if you want to use NHibernate 3 with MVCContrib.Castle. For anyone who wants to know exactly what needs to be done, I've blogged it at http://rageshkrishna.com/blog/2011/01/05/GettingTheLatestMVCContribNHibernateAndCastleToPlayNicely.aspx